# Quickblox sending push messages uninterruptedly

Tags: quickblox

I am facing a problem on MESSAGES module of Quickblox, and I have no idea if the error is in my code or if it is a bug.

In my code, I registered the device to receive push messages, I created the APS certificate and everything goes fine, I see my device in subscriptions tab, I can send push messages in Sandbox and Distribution enviroments. But problem is when I send a push message from dashboard or receive because of the chat (offline messages), the MESSAGE didn't change the DELIVERED status (there are 2 devices with subscription and both receive the message continuously), so I keep receiving the messages until I delete it!

> APNS (Apple Push)  Delivered: 0, failed: 0  Download detailed log
>
> Event log 2014-10-14 15:09:07 UTC : queued 2 notifications

The log is empty, then seems Apple is doing it's part correctly.

I have no idea what is wrong, I created a new dev and prod certificate, generated new APS dev and prod p12, re-created my provisioning profiles and nothing.

Could someone help me?

Comment: how do you subscribe user for push notifications? Try to remove all you subscriptions and subscribe again

Comment: thanks for your reply Igor! I realized what was wrong. Going to answer my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized where was my mistake. I created the provisioning profile with APS included, but it was set up only in TARGETS. On PROJECT it was with an old provisioning profile.

I just made the changes and now everything is going fine!